# Sidemenu and scrollable form/container

Tags: codenameone

If a form has scrollable container (tabs for ex), opening and closing the sidemenu also scrolls the containers below.

Is there a way to disable that ?

Answer (score 0):

Tabs aren't scrollable, they are swipable. You can disable the swiping of the tabs or disable the swiping of the components. The side menu is swipable only from the left most portion of the screen so the rest of the screen is safe to swipe through.